# Flask - request.files.getlist() - do not skip empty

Tags: python, flask

I have form with 4 file inputs and 4 text inputs

**Form image**:

[image]

**HTML Code**:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('Test.Test') }}" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data >

 <input type="file" name="Image"/>
 <input type="text" name="Name"/><br/>
 <input type="file" name="Image"/>
 <input type="text" name="Name"/><br/>
 <input type="file" name="Image"/>
 <input type="text" name="Name"/><br/>
 <input type="file" name="Image"/>
 <input type="text" name="Name"/><br/>
 <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I fill up only 3/4 file inputs and all text inputs

When I am tried to process this form with this code:

```
GetFiles = request.files.getlist('Image')
Name = request.form.getlist('Name')
for x, y in zip(GetFiles, Name):
   print x, y
```

**Expected result**:

```
<FileStorage: u'1.jpeg' ('image/jpeg')> 1
<FileStorage: u'2.jpeg' ('image/jpeg')> 2
None 3
<FileStorage: u'3.jpeg' ('image/jpeg')> 4
```

**But I get**:

```
<FileStorage: u'1.jpeg' ('image/jpeg')> 1
<FileStorage: u'2.jpg' ('image/jpeg')> 2
<FileStorage: u'3.jpeg' ('image/jpeg')> 3
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please include relevant HTML here.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line: `GetFiles` has 3 elements (because only 3 files were selected), `Name` has 4 elements. [Python zip doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) says:

> The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

*You* know which "Image" goes with which "Text", but the computer does not. One approach:

- in the html: give each Image input a unique name, something like `name="Image-1"`.
- in the py: iterate over `Names` and "get" the image that goes with
  that name (something like `request.files.get('Image-'+{index})`
- Don't forget, `get()` will return `None` if key is not found
- Don't forget, if you iterate over Names with something like
  `range(len(Names))` it will be 0-indexed.